# About the angular custom control with multiple text input problem

Tags: angular

My source code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibssyd).

In order to show a list of manuals attributes in varies part of the web site,
I built a custom control that has multiple text fields (i.e. the ManualListComponent).

I embed this control to a form. Although I change the manual location value, even empty the manual location, why the form.dirty always return false?

Comment: Could you please add the revelent part of your code in your question ?

Comment: There are many things you lack, I recommend you follow a tutorial: https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control